# WinAPI - Loading Ressources from a DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm developing an applicaion for Windows 7 with VisualStudio2017. This application wants to have special cursors which are loaded from a DLL. So first I created a DLL and added the following .rc file:

```
BM_CURSOR_GRAB          CURSOR               "./grab.cur"
BM_CURSOR_GRABBING      CURSOR               "./grabbing.cur"
```

BM_CURSOR_GRAB and BM_CURSOR_GRABBING are defined in a header file as:

```
#define BM_CURSOR_GRAB     100
#define BM_CURSOR_GRABBING 101
```

I compile the DLL - that works and check it with `ResourceEditor.exe` My resources are included:

[image: Picture from the Resource Editor]

Now the "non working" part starts. My application wants to load the cursor, but `FindResource` doesn't find it. Here is my code:

```
HMODULE dll    = LoadLibrary("BenjaMiniRessources.dll");
HRSRC   hRes   = FindResource(dll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), RT_CURSOR);
DWORD   dwSize = SizeofResource(dll,hRes);
HGLOBAL hMem   = LoadResource(dll, hRes);
LPBYTE  pBytes = (LPBYTE)LockResource(hMem);

Cursor = CreateIconFromResource(pBytes, dwSize, false, 0x00030000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - not checking for failure, not calling `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Have you tried enumerating the resources. RT_CURSOR resources are not, iirc, included included directly in the resource section, they are more, typically, included as sub resources in a RT_GROUP_CURSOR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simply [LoadCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the corresponding hInstance. This works in the MFC and all of my Windows applications.

Comment: Ok! That works... But how should one know that I could use a Module as an Instance?! Argh... WinAPI...
Thank you!

Comment: @DragonEgg per the [Win32 Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) documentation: "*HMODULE and HINSTANCE are the same in current versions of Windows, but represented different things in 16-bit Windows.*" Also see [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903) in Raymond Chen's blog.

Answer (score 4):

when you include 
`BM_CURSOR_GRAB CURSOR "./grab.cur"` line to rc file, in generated PE will be `(BM_CURSOR_GRAB, RT_GROUP_CURSOR)` resource. so type will be `RT_GROUP_CURSOR` but not `RT_CURSOR`.

then you need call [`LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648074(v=vs.85).aspx) function for get name (id) of cursor that best fits the specified size.

after this you need again load resource - already `RT_CURSOR` with id returned from [`LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648074(v=vs.85).aspx).

and finally use it in call [`CreateIconFromResourceEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648061(v=vs.85).aspx).

but however, more simply call [`LoadImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx) with `IMAGE_CURSOR` resource type.

```
(HCURSOR)LoadImageW(hmod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BM_CURSOR_GRAB), IMAGE_CURSOR, 
            0, 0, 0);
```

for example, for use actual resource size. or is you want use default system cursor size:

```
(HCURSOR)LoadImageW(hmod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BM_CURSOR_GRAB), IMAGE_CURSOR, 
                GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR), 0);
```

or

```
(HCURSOR)LoadImageW(hmod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BM_CURSOR_GRAB), IMAGE_CURSOR, 
                    0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

or simply

```
LoadCursorW(hmod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BM_CURSOR_GRAB));
```

last call internal call `LoadImageW` with `LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED` flags

however code for direct access resource (`LoadImageW` do this internal)

```
ULONG GetResourcePointer(void** ppv, ULONG* pcb, HMODULE hModule, PCWSTR lpName, PCWSTR lpType)
{
    if (HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType))
    {
        if (HGLOBAL hResData = LoadResource(hModule, hResource))
        {
            if (PVOID pv = LockResource(hResData))
            {
                if (ULONG cb = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource))
                {
                    *ppv = pv, *pcb = cb;

                    return NOERROR;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

        ULONG err = NOERROR;
        HCURSOR hcur;

        if (HMODULE hmod = (HMODULE)LoadLibraryW(L"*"))
        {
            ULONG cb, err;
            PVOID pv;
            if (!(err = GetResourcePointer(&pv, &cb, hmod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BM_CURSOR_GRAB), RT_GROUP_CURSOR)))
            {
                if (int nID = LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx((PBYTE)pv, FALSE, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR))
                {

                    if (!(err = GetResourcePointer(&pv, &cb, hmod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nID), RT_CURSOR)))
                    {
                        if (!(hcur = (HCURSOR)CreateIconFromResourceEx((PBYTE)pv, cb,
                            FALSE, 0x00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR|LR_DEFAULTSIZE)))
                        {
                            err = GetLastError();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    err = GetLastError();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This works as well... But It's quite... complex D: And... I have no clue how to figure that out...

Your answer is much closer to my problem then the first one - but I mark the first one as solved because it's easier to use.

Comment: @DragonEgg - but i at begin say that `LoadImageW` is best solution for you. the `LoadCursorW` is particular case of `LoadImageW` if you agree use default size for cursor. the code, which i provide - only for demo

Answer (score 0):

Variants of errors:

1. The system does not find the library with the specified name BenjaMiniRessources.dll, if the return value in `LoadLibrary("BenjaMiniRessources.dll")` is NULL;
2. The system does not find a resource of type RT_CURSOR in BenjaMiniRessources.dll, if the return value in  `FindResource(dll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), RT_CURSOR)` is NULL. (Maybe type of this resource is RT_GROUP_CURSOR or RT_ANICURSOR);
3. The error is in string `SizeofResource(dll,hRes),` if return value is NULL;
4. The problem is in `LoadResource(dll, hRes)`, if this function returns NULL;
5. The fault in `LockResource(hMem)`, if this function returns NULL;
6. The error is in string `CreateIconFromResource(pBytes, dwSize, false, 0x00030000)`.

You can go through the code under the debugger and see which one of the lines of the program first returns an error.

Comment: *if the return value in LoadLibrary is less than 32;* - look like you confuse `LoadLibrary` and `ShellExecute`. the `LoadLibrary` on fail return exactly 0 and return value must be compared with 0 only (not 32). and not may be `this resource is RT_GROUP_CURSOR` but exactly

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused LoadLibrary() and LoadModule().